# DRY attribute selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an element on the page:

```
<div data-name='foo'>
```

What's the best way to get the attribute value? Is there anything more DRY than `$('[data-name]').attr('data-name')` or `$('[data-name]').data('name')`?

Comment: `$("div['data-name']").data("name")`

Comment: Define _"DRY"_ please. What's not "DRY" with this code?

Comment: `if (x < 0) x = 1` isn't _"DRY"_ because you wrote `x` twice?

Comment: @gdoron I define DRY as not repeating yourself and in this situation, the same string is repeated.

In your example, yes it's technically not "DRY", but it's an example where the syntax/language is probably justified in not trying to make it DRY. Then again, in some languages, you could indeed substitute something like $_ or $0 or whatever for the "x", so it's a matter of language preference too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how do you define *"DRY"*...
`if (x < 0) x = 1` isn't "DRY" because you wrote x twice?

Anyway **with the current DOM structure, no there is not.** The selector is inefficient which is more important!

You can give the element an id, which make the code faster.

```
<div id='foo' data-name='foo'> </div>
```

...

```
$('#foo').data('name'); // That's more like it.
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know what this has to do with 'Don't Repeat Yourself', but if you don't have a cached reference to this node you would have to use that, rather verbose, call.

It might be a good idea to have at least an `id` for the nodes. The DOM query for that is lighting fast in comparison to that attribute-selector. But afterall, it's still the fastest technique to store a reference in a variable, like

```
var myNode = $('[data-name]');
```

and then use that variable throughout your whole application

```
myNode.data( 'name' );
```

Comment: I think the DRY reference is because you have to repeat the name of the attribute. e.g. `$('[data-zebra]').data('zebra')`. Change the name to 'horse', and you have to change it twice.

Comment: That's just about as related to DRY as `if( x < 0 ) x = 0;` would be.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a plugin that did something like this. I'm not sure the additional overhead is worth it, though.

```
function getData(varName) {

  var selector = '[data-' + varName + ']';
  return $(selector).data(varName);

}
```

(not tested)

Comment: ?! write a plugin that append `data-` to you selector? **Get real!**

Comment: @gdoron Yep, I agree - I don't think it's worth the overhead. However, the question was 'how do I make this DRY?' and that's the only way I can think of doing it.

Comment: Instead of teaching him how to write bad code (Which I agree he requested) , You can teach him how to write good code... **=)**

Comment: I didn't request bad code, I just asked if it was possible. I could certainly conceive of the library providing a built-in function for this kind of thing, or someone having some tricky way to do it based on the existing functions. There's plenty of syntactic sugar in jQuery which could be replaced by a one or two line plugin using other jQuery methods (e.g. appendTo can easily be replaced by append).

Comment: @mahemoff It's probably a good idea to put a bit of context in the question. Given your rating, I assume you know what you're doing and have answered accordingly. But understanding what you're trying to do and why makes it easier to help.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't expecting the response this received either! I was just checking if there's some jQuery shortcut I missed, as there often is, and it's a little complicated and obscure to explain anyway. FWIW it's a single-page app where the element in question is a pseudo-page ID which keeps changing (data-page). So while I could technically use an element ID (#), it feels a little semantically wrong (and may also cause bugs if it's cached anywhere) to have the same ID to be tied to different elements.

Answer (score 0):

Without a tag qualifier (e.g. `div[data-name]`) your selector will be very inefficient as it will have to traverse the entire DOM to check for matching elements.

It would be much preferable to identify a specific ID (or even a class) to help out the selector engine and restrict how much of the DOM has to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't repeat that everywhere, (i.e cache the result), I don't really see how you can get anything more DRY.

```
var name = $('[data-name]').data('name');
```

You're technically not repeating yourself yet.